# Java Image compression

Tags: java, image-compression

From our application we fetch images (jpeg/png) from a third party service, after download we want to save these images as compressed.

Can any one please guide how to compress images in Java ?

Comment: JPEG and PNG images *are* compressed.

Comment: I think you need to look at image slicing. Photoshop has this and it makes it an image load faster. Please check slice technique and see if that can help you.

Answer (score 5):

JPG and PNG images already *are* compressed, so it's not entirely clear what your intention is. However, in general, you can write images with `ImageIO`:

```
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", outputStream);
```

(or `"png"`, analogously). By default, this does not allow you to select the compression *level* (that is, the trade-off between file size and image quality). In order to write a JPG file with a different than the default compression, you can use a utility method like this:

```
public static void writeJPG(
    BufferedImage bufferedImage,
    OutputStream outputStream,
    float quality) throws IOException
{
    Iterator<ImageWriter> iterator =
        ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg");
    ImageWriter imageWriter = iterator.next();
    ImageWriteParam imageWriteParam = imageWriter.getDefaultWriteParam();
    imageWriteParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
    imageWriteParam.setCompressionQuality(quality);
    ImageOutputStream imageOutputStream =
        new MemoryCacheImageOutputStream(outputStream);
    imageWriter.setOutput(imageOutputStream);
    IIOImage iioimage = new IIOImage(bufferedImage, null, null);
    imageWriter.write(null, iioimage, imageWriteParam);
    imageOutputStream.flush();
}
```

Comment: Hi Marco13, Thanks for you reply. Let me elaborate more. We are building a realstats application, there are lot of properties and each property has 10 to 30 .jpeg image. When a property is selected, its corresponding images are shown. Is there any way to compress/ reduce size the images to load fast?  Let me know if you want more details

Comment: Compression is usually only indirectly related to the time that is required for *loading* the images. A compressed image might load faster (because less data has to be read from the hard disk), but this would have to be validated with a benchmark (although I doubt that is is possible to *sensibly* validate this). General hints for possible optimizations (like caching or pre-loading the images in a background thread) are beyond the scope of this comment.